# Get specific field in array mongodb and return as array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoskin

I have the following document:

```
{
    array: [
        {
            type: 'error',
            data: 1
        },
        {
            type: 'error',
            data: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there anyway for my to get only the data field in each array element and return it as an array? Like the following:

```
[1, 2] // <--- array containing only the data fields
```

The [mongodb projection documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/) doesn't seem to cover this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use aggregation and the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": { "_id": 0, "data": { 
            "$map": { "input": "$array", "as": "ar", "in": "$$ar.data" } } }
    }
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{ "data" : [ 1, 2 ] }
```